# Implementing a Case Statement in U-SQL

Tags: u-sql

Wondering if anyone has suggestions on implementing a case or IF statement with U-SQL. For example, how do i convert this:

```
SELECT
    FirstName, LastName,
    Salary, DOB,
    CASE Gender
        WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male'
        WHEN 'F' THEN 'Female'
    END
FROM Employees;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use an inline C# expression for simple things like so (did not test it yet though)

```
SELECT
    FirstName, LastName,
    Salary, DOB,
    Gender == "Male" ? "M" : "F"
FROM Employees
```

If it is more complex consider writing a user defined operator in C#.
Have a look at the MSDN tutorial [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-develop-user-defined-operators/)

Answer (score 3):

An example of using ?: in lieu of CASE is available at the official U-SQL Language Reference site under [Common SQL Expressions in U-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt771654.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

U-SQL supports the ANSI `CASE` expression as per the release notes [here](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2018/2018_Spring/USQL_Release_Notes_2018_Spring.md#u-sql-supports-ansi-sql-case-expression), since Spring 2018.  A simple example:

```
DECLARE @outputFile string = @"\output\output.csv";

@Employees =
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES
        ( "w", "Bob", 1999, "31/12/1999", "M" ),
        ( "Sheena", "Easton", 1999, "31/12/1998", "F" )
        ) AS Employees(FirstName, LastName, Salary, dob, Gender);


@output =
    SELECT FirstName,
           LastName,
           Salary,
           dob,
           CASE Gender
               WHEN "M" THEN "Male"
               WHEN "F" THEN "Female"
           END AS Gender
    FROM @Employees;


OUTPUT @output
TO @outputFile
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting : false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution above is correct. But I'd prefer to use IF instead inline C# code.

```
SELECT
    FirstName, LastName,
    Salary, DOB,
    IF(Gender == "Male", "M", "F") AS Gender
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT 
    FirstName, LastName,
    Salary, DOB,
    **(Gender ==  'M') ? 'Male' 

    (Gender ==  'F') ? 'Female' AS Gender**
FROM Employees;

This will Work on your Case

Answer (score 0):

As other answers did not provide the exact equivalent, I am providing the same below.

The corresponding expression in U-SQL is. We have to use conditional expression (`?:`). For more information, you can refer to below links:

[C# Expressions for ?:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/csharp-functions-and-operators-u-sql#condl)
[TSQL and USQL equivalents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/common-sql-expressions-in-u-sql#case)

```
SELECT
    FirstName, LastName,
    Salary, DOB,
    (Gender == "M") ? "Male" : (Gender == "F") ? "Female" : "Unknown" AS Gender
FROM Employees;
```